# Android Studio 0.9.1 Won't Refresh Project - Could not run build action

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm attempting to upgrade to AS 0.9.1 from 0.8.13 which necessitates an upgrade from gradle 1.12 to 2.1 and the gradle plugin from 0.12.2 to 0.14.0.

My app compiles using the command line  e.g.

./gradlew assembleQaDebug but fails whenever I try to do anything in the IDE.

The Messages pane shows:
Gradle 'BespokeOffers' project refresh failed
Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-bin.zip'.

The idea log has a monster stack trace, the salient points of which seem to be

```
2014-11-05 12:12:02,972 [ 774138]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at '/Users/agf/Development/bespoke-offers-android/BespokeOffers' 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-bin.zip'.
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.model.SourceProviderImpl.cloneProvider(SourceProviderImpl.java:56)
```

Comment: try 2 thing : delete then reimport the proj in gradle and see whether the init 'sync' will work :in the ./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.props ... try chg 'gradle-2.1-bin.zip' to gradle-2.1-all.zip

Comment: Thanks Robert - I've tried both those to no avail.  I've also tried deleting my ~/.gradle directory to force a complete clean out and rebuild of the gradle cache.  Frustratingly, if I create a new project it works just fine - I just can't import my existing one!

Comment: delete the .iml file in proj root folder. delete the AS proj. import the project again.  and that's not working? hmmmmm maybe gradle 0.14.1

Comment: FWIW according to 'gradle -version'  . im still on 1.10 on my linux box and all the imports stuff with AS 0.9.1 and complex , multi-library projects is now good ... i dont mess with system wide gradle- just with the project level wrapper properties...

Comment: When i got warnings about internal gradle rev, i just clicked on the links and it did not impact my system level gradle AFAIK

Comment: Apparently other people have discovered a problem with a third party plugin - `'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test'` - and that has been fixed, but it didn't work for me and we are using a ton of other 3rd party plugins -- so it might be a slow process of elimination....  Thanks for your suggestions